# Scrapy KeyError: 0 parse next page

Tags: python, scrapy, keyerror

**Set-up**

I'm scraping [this website](https://en.spitogatos.gr/sale) for its housing ads, using Scrapy and Python 3.7

Per housing ad, I obtain the house's characteristics like size, price, etc.

The site displays its ads in 10 per page, so I need to iterate over pages.

---

**My code**

```
class DwellingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dwelling'

    start_urls = list(df['spitogatos_url'])

    def parse(self, response):  

        # obtain ad list element
        result_list = response.css('#searchDetailsListings')            

        # select ad from list
        for ad in result_list.xpath('div'):

            # here's the code to obtain characterstics per ad and yield them

        # obtain next page url 
        next_page = response.css('#pagination > ul > li.next > a').xpath('@href').extract_first()

        # send next page url to parse function
        if len(next_page) > 0:
            yield scrapy.Request(str(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

where `list(df['spitogatos_url'])` is a list containing the X urls I want to scrape and looks like,

```
['https://en.spitogatos.gr/search/results/residential/sale/r194/m194m?ref=refinedSearchSR',
 'https://en.spitogatos.gr/search/results/residential/sale/r153/m153m187m?ref=refinedSearchSR']
```

---

**Issue**

Obtaining the house characteristics per ad works.

The problem lies with `GET`ting the next page correctly,

```
[scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://en.spitogatos.gr/search/results/residential/sale/r194/m194m/offset_10> (referer: https://en.spitogatos.gr/search/results/residential/sale/r194/m194m?ref=refinedSearchSR)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4730, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 88, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 992, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

I'm not sure what causes this `KeyError: 0` and how to solve it.

Any ideas?

---

**Edit**

I found that if I use a `next_page_url` as starting point, i.e.

```
start_urls = ['https://en.spitogatos.gr/search/results/residential/sale/r177/m177m183m/offset_10']
```

I immediately get the same error,

```
ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://en.spitogatos.gr/search/results/residential/sale/r177/m177m183m/offset_10> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4730, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 88, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 992, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
next_page = response.css('[rel="next"] ::attr(href)').extract_first()

if next_page:
    yield scrapy.Request(str(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but issue persists.

Comment: Can you provide me `start_urls`?

Comment: For example, `https://en.spitogatos.gr/search/results/residential/sale/r194/m194m?ref=refinedSearchSR`

Comment: I found that when I start the spider with the next page url, i.e. `start_urls = ['https://en.spitogatos.gr/search/results/residential/sale/r177/m177m183m/offset_10']` I get the same issue immediately.

Comment: I have updated the answers with a screenshot. The above code is working for me.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I realized the issue was caused by the code gathering the ad's characteristics. An issue that only fired on the 2nd and subsequent pages but works on the first.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the array in the start_urls. I had the same problem and just now I'm trying without an array and, at the moment, the error is not happening.